# Node.js singlethreading concept

Tags: node.js

If I have a long running process in Node, how do I run that process while still remaining responsive to new user requests?

In other languages, such as Java, we could simply start a daemon (background) thread and run the process on that. But with Node, if it's truly singlethreaded, how does this work?

Answer (score 1):

There's a concept of event-loop. When your node process does any I/O operation (ie. reading from db etc.), it puts the current request into the event-loop, and the thread moves onto the next request. When the I/O is done, the thread picks up the `callback` from the event-loop, and responds to the user.

Because of this paradigm, node.js is able to handle many requests in one thread, as opposed of creating a thread per requests.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is non-blocking, routines are run asynchronously permitting processing before the previous execution is finished. This way, if you have multiple user requests they all will be executed at the same time (up to the capacity of the CPU obviously).

try this code for example

```
function myUserRequest(order, cb) {
   // to simulate some lengthy operation we use a timeout
   setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(order + ' calling callback');
      cb();
   }, 100);
}

myUserRequest(1, function () {/*some stuff to do after operation is done*/});
myUserRequest(2, function () {
    console.log('do stuff after this function is finished in a callback');
});
console.log('i am being executed already');
```

the output would be:

```
i am being executed already
2 calling callback
do stuff after this function is finished in a callback
1 calling callback
```

Note the order of the callbacks, those functions would not be executed in any particular order of calling them but rather whichever way CPU happened to schedule them.

So, your user requests would be coming in and executed at that time as long as CPU is capable of keeping up with those.

Hope this helps

Additionally I can advise you to have a look at [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) those guys got a ton of knowledge related to java script.

Answer (score 1):

in node you can spawn a child process to run the computation, pass it the input data, and it can return the computed results.  No you can't multithread your app, but there are some possibilities nevertheless.

Note that spawning a node process is fairly expensive (.04 sec plus libraries) so you might want to have a few compute workers alwayas running and farm out the work as it comes in; see the [worker-farm](http://npmjs.org/package/worker-farm) package for example.

Comment: just to point out the fact that with node.js you don't need this to achieve what threads are normally used for in other languages. The major reason why you would want multiple processes is when you have access to multi-core processor and what to utilise it fully. More often the not, the application would be run on small, shared instances on the cloud, with single CPUs which makes this technique UN-applicable :)

Comment: in my experience multiple processes were used to deliver results faster (by splitting up the work).  Node has clusters, but the only parallelism available to node is at the service (http) request level.  Oh, and the small cloud instances I've worked with had 2-4 cores each.